# How many time the string matches

Tags: c, regex, pattern-matching

I have a pattern like this one here `*b*` and a string like this one "abcdb" witch is matches twice.

I want to calculate the number of time string matches, but I have no clue how to achieve this in C language since I'm just a beginner.

Is there any hints of how can make this function in c?

Comment: In plain simple standard C? You can't, since C doesn't have any regular expression functions. There are other ways to do it than regular expressions though. I suggest you read a little about the [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) function.

Comment: Yes, I know but I need way out with the asterisk, sorry that It didn't show up earlier, I 've modified my question.

Comment: Then you need to learn about regular expressions, because what you show (after your edit) is *not* a regular expression. It's a *globbing* pattern, and it would match your string *once*. Unless it's a requirement for the exercise to use regular expressions, then *don't*. There a saying going something like this: "I have a problem. I solved it with regular expressions. Now I have *two* problems." Regular expressions are almost always overkill, like using a shotgun to kill a mosquito. To find all occurrences of the sub-string `"b"` in `"abcdb"` all you need is the *standard* `strstr` function.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple pattern like `*b*`, you can use `strstr` defined in `<string.h>`:

- Initialize a `const char *p = "abcdb";`
- for each match `p = strstr(p, "b");`
- count the match and increment `p` by one if the matches can overlap or by the length of the pattern if they cannot.
- when there is no match, you have the total count.

For more complex regular expressions, there is no standard function to match generic patterns. You can try a install a regex library or write your own engine, a *non trivial task*, so say the least.

Here is the code:

```
#include <string.h>

// works for simplistic patterns without any wildcards
int count_matches(const char *s, const char *pattern) {
    char *p;
    int count = 0;
    for (p = s; (p = strstr(p, pattern)) != NULL; p++)
        count++;
    return count;
}
```

If your system supports Posix filename pattern matching, you could use `fnmatch()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int result = 0;
char* pattern  = strdup("b");
char* mystr = strdup("abcdb");

if(strlen(pattern) <= strlen(mystr))
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i <= strlen(mystr) - strlen(pattern); i++){
        if(strncmp(pattern, mystr + i, strlen(pattern)) == 0){
            result += 1;
        }
    }
}

free(pattern);
free(mystr);
printf("%d\n", result);

return result;
```

Don't forget to `#include <string.h>` and `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: Still 2 more issues: no need to allocate copies, undefined behavior if `strlen(pattern) > strlen(mystr)`

Comment: The reason for undefined behavior is non obvious: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` which is an unsigned type. Hence if `strlen(pattern) > strlen(mystr)`, the expression `strlen(mystr) - strlen(pattern)` is a huge unsigned value and the expression `i <= strlen(mystr) - strlen(pattern)`, evaluated using unsigned arithmetic stays true for values of `i` much beyond the length of `mystr`, eventually producing undefined behavior when `strncmp()` dereferences `mystr + i`.

Comment: @chqrlie Right. Is there still anything wrong? I wonder if `mystr+i` will work or not O.o

Comment: You still make copies of the string and pattern for no reason and should compute the string lengths just once.